# What does a subscript on a column vector respresent

Tags: econometrics, notation

I'm reading the Greene book on econometrics and am much confused by some of the notation. E.g., in the following equation (Econometric Analysis 6th ed.pg. 50), what does **b**<sub>0</sub> represent?

Var[**b**|**X**] $\leq$ Var[**b**<sub>0</sub>|**X**]

I'm pretty sure that **b** is a column vector, I simply do not understand the significance of the subscript.

Comment: It would be helpful to give a full reference (+ page & equation number) to the book. (I'd guess $\mathbf{b}_0$ is just some other vector, but this should be defined in the book)

Comment: I think it is from Greene, William H. 2011. *Econometric Analysis*. 7th ed. Pearson, page 61 (4.3.6: The Implications of the Stochastic Regressors). In the previous subsection (4.3.5), $b_0$ is defined: "Let b$_0$ = Cy be another linear unbiased estimator of $\beta$, where C is a $K \times n$ matrix" .

Comment: Michael, in what way doesn't the quotation by @T.E.G. (which presumably you were aware of when you posted) fully answer your question?